# PHP pass querystring to another page

Tags: php, mysql, export, query-string, export-to-excel

I have three files. The main file is dispatch.php. From the this file, the user would make various selections which uses a query builder on another page called dispatch-grid.php. In dispatch-grid.php, the query is built and displayed to dispatch.php.

Here is the query from dispatch-grid.php that calls the database and displays the grid on dispatch.php:

```
 <?php
   $select = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `dispatch_read`" . " WHERE " . $where . ";";
   $QueryResult = @mysql_query($select) or die ();
   $resnum = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);

   if($resnum == 0){
      echo "<div>Your search returned no results</div>";
   }
   else {
     echo "<table>\n";
     echo "<thead><tr>" .
     echo "<th>BOL</th>" .
     echo "<th>CONTAINER</th>" .
     echo "<th>STATUS</th>" . 
     echo "</tr></thead>" .
     echo "<tbody>\n";

     while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[BOL]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[CONTAINER]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[STATUS]}</td>";
     echo "</tr></tbody>\n";
     echo "</table>\n";
     }
    }
```

There are many more rows that I display. I was just trying to keep this as short as possible.

I can display this grid on dispatch.php by using this function:

```
 displayrecords();
```

At this point, the grid is displayed on dispatch.php.  What I need to do now is pass the querystring from dispatch-grid.php ($select) to another page, called getreport.php where I will be able to export the grid into an excel sheet.

On dispatch.php, I have an input button:

```
 <input onclick="getreport()" type="button" value="Get Report" />
```

The button calls a javascript function on the same page:

```
 *** UPDATE ***
 function getreport(){
   window.location = "getreport.php?where=$where";
 }
```

At this point, I am able to open an excel sheet, but it opens up blank.  I'm not sure if it's necessary to show, but here is the code on getreport.php:

```
 <?php
 include("include/database.php";

 global $header;
 global $data;
 global $ts;
 $ts = date('mdY-His');
 $sep = "\t";
 $filename = "excelfilename";

 *** UPDATE ***
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dispatch_read WHERE " . $_GET['where'] . ";";

 $result = @mysql_query($sql) or die ("Couldn't execute query" . mysql_error());
 $file_ending = "xls";

 header("Content-Type: application/xls");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");

 $sep = "\t";
 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
 echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
 }
 print("\n");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
   {
     $schema_insert = "";
     for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
     {
       if(!isset($row[$j]))
         $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
       elseif ($row[$j] != "")
         $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
       else
         $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
     }
   $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert .= "\t";
   print(trim($schema_insert));
   print "\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Please disregard any typos. I am able to display the grid with no issues. My code works up until they click the getreport button.

I am guessing what I need to do is send the query ($select) from dispatch-grid.php to getreport.php, but I am not sure how to do it.

I tried doing this on dispatch.php:

```
 $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

I then tried to send that to getreport.php, but I was unsuccessful sending it.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: what value $where holds?

Comment: $where holds the various selections that the user made via dropdown selections.  I didn't display it because I didn't think it was necessary to show. At this point the grid displays on dispatch.php.  All I need to do is send $select from dispatch-grid.php to getreport.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply alter this function (getreport) to pass the whatever params required to `getreport.php`

```
function getreport(){
   window.location = "getreport.php?param1=hello&param2=world";
 }
```

so in getrport.php, you can simply access these params as,

```
echo $_GET['param1'];
echo $_GET['param2'];
```

**Update**

what you mean to pass is,    **$select = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `dispatch_read`" . " WHERE " . $where . ";";**

what i am suggesting is to pass only the $where variable value to getreport.php.

i.e

```
function getreport(){
   window.location = "getreport.php?where=hello"; // where param should hold the value of $where 
 }
```

so in **getreport.php**, you can access it as following and do the same.

**$select = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `dispatch_read`" . " WHERE " . $_GET['where'] . ";";**

Comment: I am not sure I follow this. How do I send $select using what you showed me above? Thank you so much in advance for you help.

Comment: I am getting this error:  Unknown column '$where' in 'where clause'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what change did you do to get that error ? please update the question including your attempt with code sample

Comment: it should be the dropdown value which user selected. window.location = "getreport.php?where=$where";

Comment: i.e window.location = "getreport.php?where="+$('#yourdropdownID').val();